# Determine day of week of given week

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to do this:

Say I want to look at the week that is 12 weeks from today's date.  How would I go about determining a specific date, say Tuesday of that week?

Example:

I want to set a meeting up 6 weeks from now.  I always have my meetings on Fridays.  How would I get to that date?

Comment: Yes it absolutely is. What have you tried?

Comment: Apple's "Date and Time Programming Guide" has dozens of examples for calendrical calculations, such as "Getting the Sunday in the current week". Have a look, it should get you started!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSInteger numberOfWeeksToAdd = 6;
NSInteger targetWeekday = 5; // thursday

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comps.week = numberOfWeeksToAdd;
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *futureDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:today options:0];
NSDateComponents *futureDateComps = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:futureDate];

NSInteger weekday = futureDateComps.weekday;
NSDateComponents *c = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
c.day = targetWeekday - weekday;

NSDate *resultDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:c toDate:futureDate options:0];
```

numberOfWeeksToAdd - weeks count, targetWeekday - number from 1 to 7 (1 - Sunday) which represents a day of the week.

resultDate - thursday after 6 weeks from current date